# 2 checkboxes -- One of them does not work

Tags: php

I have a strange problem.This is my form if User is banned, checkbox is checked , if not, checkbox is empty.

```
<tr>
    <td>{$user4.username}</td>
    <td>{$user4.email}</td>
    <td>{$user4.name} {$user4.surname}</td>
    {if !$user4.banned}
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value="{$user4.id}" /></center></td>
    {else}
       <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan2" value="{$user4.id}" checked /></center></td>
    {/if}
    {if $user4.status}
    <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheck" value="{$user4.id}"></center></td>
    {else}
      <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="removeCheckNoRemove" value="{$user4.id}" checked></center></td>
    {/if}
</tr>
```

In controller side, i use below code.BancheckBan is working properly.However, banCheckBan2 is not working.What might be the reason ?

```
 if (isset($_POST['updateBanRemove'])) {

            if (isset($_POST['banCheckBan2']))
                  NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 0))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckBan2'])->execute();
           elseif (isset($_POST['banCheckBan'])){
                NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 1))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckBan'])->execute();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['banCheckBan2']))
                  NCore::db('USER')->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 0))->eq('ID', $_POST['banCheckBan2'])->execute(); this does not working but banCheckBan is working . What's missing?

Comment: You may need to add tags to this question. Are you using a framework or a templating library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `checked` checkboxes will be send to the server. So, your condition will fail to unban a user when unchecking a checkbox.

One possibility to address this might be:

(View Side)

```
<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="{$user4.id}" />

{if !$user4.banned}
  <td>
    <center>
      <input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value="1" />
    </center>
  </td>
{else}
  <td>
    <center>
      <input type="checkbox" name="banCheckBan" value="1" checked />
    </center>
  </td>
{/if}
```

(Controller Side)

```
if (isset($_POST['updateBanRemove'])) {
  if (!isset($_POST['banCheckBan'])) {
    NCore::db('USER')
      ->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 0))
      ->eq('ID', $_POST['userID'])
      ->execute();
  } elseif ($_POST['banCheckBan']) {
    NCore::db('USER')
      ->updateAsArray(array('BANNED' => 1))
      ->eq('ID', $_POST['userID'])
      ->execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: still uncheck does not work . :D

Comment: Your solution is wonderful ty.

Comment: @Alexander - what technology is in use here? Is this Smarty? If you'd retag, that'd be great. +1

Comment: @halfer, only the OP can know for sure. That's why I haven't retagged it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't the checkbox you are comparing against need to be same for if and else if you are checking its value?